# How can we clean up the ABD questions

Tags: discussion

There are several similar ABD questions:

- [When can a person be called a PhD ABD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28717/when-can-a-person-be-called-a-phd-abd?s=2|1.0932)
- [Can someone call themselves Dr. so and so (ABD)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/52212/can-someone-call-themselves-dr-so-and-so-abd?s=3|0.9685)
- [How to address a doctoral candidate who is ABD (All but Dissertation)? Is "Dr" appropriate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24601/how-to-address-a-doctoral-candidate-who-is-abd-all-but-dissertation-is-dr-a?s=5|0.8338)

Seems like they should really be collapsed, suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

They're not exactly the same as one another. Respectively:

- When can someone use "ABD" as a title
- Can someone who is ABD call *themself* Dr.
- What should *I* call someone who is ABD.

They're not eligible for merging (not exact duplicates). They're similar, sure, but we have lots of similar questions on the site - I'm not sure why these are a problem.

Comment: I think people keep asking in the hope that someone will say it's okay to use ABD after their name --